# CABasicAnimation fromValue & CAKeyframeAnimation values error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I am animating a view (moveonView). Autolayout has been set for this view. When I give moveonView's 'y' position as fromValue in CABasicAnimation it's not in it's place during animation. I need to give some padding value to place it on it's correct position. Why is fromValue placing my view incorrectly? Breakpoint also reveals fromValue takes in correct 'y' value from "moveonView" but still placing the view incorrectly. What could be the reason.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.keyPath = @"position.y";
animation.delegate = self;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_moveonView.frame.origin.y];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.frame.size.height - 100]; //[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPosition.origin];
animation.duration = 3;
[_moveonView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"basic"];
```

I need to give some padding value to place it on exact position

```
 animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:_moveonView.frame.origin.y + 50];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame's origin and the layer's position are not the same point.

When you ask for `frame.origin.y` that is the y-coordinate of the top left corner of the view (on iOS), meaning that it's the same as `CGRectGetMinY(frame)`.

The layer's position, however, corresponds to the `center` of the view. So when you are animating `position.y` that is the same as moving the center of the view.

You could update your from value to be using `CGRectGetMidY(frame)` (note the change from mi**n** to mi**d**).

```
animation.fromValue = @( CGRectGetMidY(_moveonView.frame) );
```

Comment: That did the magic. Thank you so much for your help. Thanks for your time to explain me the concept too.